# Python converting string to dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to convert this string into a dictionary using the `JSON` library.

```
string = {u'ItemID': u'474178239', u'Status': 1, u'ImageURL': u'https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/d2/1a/d21a5497da25891c11ce39e54a1171db_best.jpg', u'Last_Modified_Date': {u'$date': u'2017-08-05T05:28:42.773Z'}, u'ClientID': 6, u'Creation_Date': {u'$date': u'2017-08-05T05:28:42.773Z'}, u'ImageName': u'288216716fb441b5f07bc61b7fc827a9.jpg', u'_id': '55315426_03', u'CategoryID': u'18019', u'Metadata': {u'productPageURL': u'https://www.shopstyle.com/p/gianvito-rossi-vamp-100-suede-ankle-boots-black/474178239', u'price': u'895', u'description': u"<![CDATA[\n                        Cap off sophisticated evening looks with Gianvito Rossi's black ankle boots. Crafted in Italy from the finest suede , this almond-toe design has a low-cut, split vamp and extended topline. Wear yours with everything from dresses to tailored pants.\n                        ]]>", u'style': u'boots', u'title': u'Gianvito Rossi - Vamp 100 Suede Ankle Boots - Black'}}
```

The string is definitely in string format:

```
type(string)
str
```

However when I try to convert it into a dictionary using:

```
dictionary = json.loads(string)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Is there anyway I can get around this?

Comment: The code you provided for variable `string` is not _string_ it is dict.

Comment: So, is your value `"string = {u'..."` (a snippet of Python code as string), or `"{u'..."` (a Python dictionary literal as string), or `{u'...` (a dictionary)? That's rather nebulous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provided object is a dictionary.
However,
try using the ast library :

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(string)
```